# Difference between a Tenant and an Azure Account

Tags: azure

Can you please explain the difference between a Microsoft Account and a Tenant? Are these equivalent terms? I know that a Tenant represents an individual or Organization, and that many subscriptions can be associated with one tenant. However, is this the same as a Microsoft Azure Account? Can an account have multiple tenants? Or vice versa - can one tenant have multiple accounts?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming by Microsoft Account you are talking about an **EA Account Owner**. A Microsoft Account is a billing term.  That is typically where your enterprise agreement is struck.  This will lay out what your costs are for various services.  A **Tenant** is an instance of Azure Active Directory.  This is where your identities live.  Each Azure subscription and M365 (think office) subscription is tied to an AAD for identity.

### Enrollment Hierarchy

[image: hierarchy image]

### What is Azure AD Tenant

An Azure AD tenant provides identity and access management (IAM) capabilities to applications and resources used by your organization. An identity is a directory object that can be authenticated and authorized for access to a resource. Identity objects exist for human identities such as students and teachers, and non-human identities like classroom and student devices, applications, and service principles.

The Azure AD tenant is an identity security boundary that is under the control of your organization’s IT department. Within this security boundary, administration of objects (such as user objects) and configuration of tenant-wide settings are controlled by your IT administrators.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/intro-azure-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/landing-zone/design-area/azure-billing-enterprise-agreement